# How to use max_by and with_index in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, max, ruby-1.9.3

```
a = %w(albatross dog horse)
a.max_by {|x| x.length }   #=> "albatross"
```

How can you use `max_by.with_index` to get the index of the max value (in this case 0)?

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a.each_with_index.max_by { |x,i| x.length }.last
```

Answer (score 2):

Found it: `a.each_with_index.max_by {|x, idx| x.length }`